# Remove text after point in a string

Tags: c#, string

So as the title says I want to know how to remove text after point in a string. E.g.

I have a string, "abcdefg@fedcba". How can I remove any text that is after the @ symbol (if we did not know what was after it)?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a request for code writing.

Comment: have you done **any** research to solve this problem? I guess this kind of questions will be asked forever if people don't learn how to research and if we encourage this by answering them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string input = "abcdefg@fedcba";
string result = input.Substring(0, input.IndexOf('@'));
```

Answer (score -1):

To make solution more flexible you can use a variable:

```
char borderCharacter = '@';
string input = '...';
string result = input.Substring(0, input.IndexOf(borderCharacter));
```

Comment: all you did was add a line of code, creating a method that returned the result would be bettwe

Comment: It seems like that line was excess.